# Count the <li>s in a <ul> with jQuery

Tags: jquery, list

I have a simple list like this:

```
<ul id="cyclelist">
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

and I am using jQuery to cycle through the list. The first problem is finding if the list has more than one elements to start with. I expect something like this to work:

```
var $list = $('#cyclelist');

if ($list.length > 1) {
  ...
}
```

But length always returns 1. Is there a better way to find the length of the list using jQuery? Or am I getting this wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try `$('#cyclelist li').length`

The problem is that $('#cyclelist') only has one element--the unordered list as a whole. If you want to know the number of list items in your unordered list, you can just add the additional selector 'li'.

Answer (score 2):

```
var $list = $('#cyclelist li');

alert($list.length);
```

Put simply: you were getting the number of ULs matching that selector.

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is selecting the dom element with id "cyclelist" which is a single element (the ul with that id). What you would like to do is select the li elements attached to that ul. To do this you can do (as mentioned)

```
    $('#cyclelist li')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#cyclelist')
```

uses a CSS selector for an element with id="cyclelist" and therefore returns one element/object reference so that's correct ;-)

What I guess you probably meant was

```
$('#cyclelist li')
```

to return the list items within the named element.

A more jQuery-esque way to go about iterating over collections of elements is to use each, c.f. http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each